# How to force form menu to stay in the same row as other hyperlinks

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, row, footer

I really need help to figure out how to make my footer content as below:

```
(left)Link1 | Link2 | DropDownForm(/left)        (right)link3(/right)
```

My footer code is:

```css
#footer {
    clear: both;
    padding: 10px 5px 5px 176px;
    position: relative;
    background: #edf2f8 url(images/bg-footer.png) top no-repeat;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add 2 div's to footer
First can be float:left & second can be float:right
Fix the widths (may be in %)
Then place your Let & Right contents in those div's